# "Thank you for considering my application" in German

Tags: phrase-request

As a way of wrapping up my job application in English, I usually write *"Thank you (very much) for considering my application"* at the end.

Is there a standard way to say this in German?

P.S. I tried searching this (otherwise very useful) [website](http://en.bab.la/phrases/application/cover-letter/english-german/#Closing), but I could not find this exact phrase.

Comment: Ok, cultural hint: I would hesitate to write this in an application.

Comment: Stephie, I appreciate your suggestion. Could you please explain the reason behind your reluctance to write this in an application? Is it just your own personal taste, or is there a general principle which advises against the above phrase or similar ones? I read e.g. that one should avoid thanking in advance (and I fully agree with that), but the above phrase seems rather harmless. Am I missing something?

Comment: Man schließt eine schriftliche Bewerbung wie jeden anderen formellen Brief: "Mit freundlichen Grüßen".

Comment: Robert: Natürlich. Ich wollte nicht ich die obige Phrase in meiner Bewerbung als Allerlestzes schreiben. Die Phrase und dann "Mit freundlichen Grüßen, Vorname Nachname". Ich dachte, dass das selbstverständlich ist.

Comment: Zvonimir, those details would better be discussed in [chat].

Comment: Ich freue mich, von Ihnen zu hören, und verbleibe // mit freundlichen Grüssen, ...

Comment: I agree with Zvonimir. Although Business German is very formal and rather stilted by NA standards, a fine balance works best. The decision of how formal, is best made "taking into consideration" (Eng. expression also considered formal-polite in many places) whether one is applying (in German or in English) to a German company, or a German company in North America, or an English language based company, that is looking for German skills. It would be expected that the most formal German Business etiquette would not be expected other than application in German to a business that operates in German

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Literally translated, thanking the HR guy for even looking at your application could be considered unnecessarily submissive (After all, he just does his job).

European culture assumes you are proud of your job, your skills and your abilities. Employer and applicant should meet at eye level - No need to be submissive here, and it could come across as low self-esteem ("Why is he begging for a job?"). There is a fine balance that needs to be adjusted without sounding arrogant.

End your application with a standard formal greeting - That is enough. If you want to add a bit of emphasis that you are really keen on this specific job or employer, add a

> Ich freue mich, bald von Ihnen zu hören,
>
> mit freundlichen Grüßen

Comment: tofro: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer. Writing such letters is a task rich in important subtleties, like the one you pointed out. In the end, I decided to end my letter with: Über eine Rückmeldung würde ich mich sehr freuen. Für eventuelle Rückfragen stehe ich Ihnen gerne zur Verfügung. Mit freundlichen Grüßen... In time I will get a feel for what is the optimal way to go in my applications, but the above general advices really helped a lot. Thanks again. Cheers.